# My CUDA JIT cache stays persistently far below CUDA_CACHE_MAXSIZE

Tags: caching, cuda

I have an OpenCL application which runs on CUDA v7.5.

The application has very many large kernels.  I am setting CUDA_CACHE_MAXSIZE to the maximum possible value, 4294967296  i.e. 4GB.  However, the total size of the files stored in the cache directory never grows above ~307MB.  It does appear that cache entries are being added / evicted (I see small changes in the total file size, and my application is definitely hitting the cache when querying for recent kernels).  It behaves as if there were some cache size limit lower than CUDA_CACHE_MAXSIZE being enforced, maybe by the opencl driver?

I would like to know what caused this, and if it is possible for me to access the full cache size of 4GB.

Comment: What makes you think you're hitting a cache limit? Why do you think your app should use more cache?

Comment: The app spends a long time compiling kernels on start-up.  From the logs, I can see it is much faster when it loads the kernels from the filesystem cache instead of compiling them from scratch (as you’d expect).  That’s why I want to use a larger cache, to get faster start up.

Comment: What makes me think I’m hitting some cache limit - across multiple servers running the same app, the size of the cache files grows on disk to around 300M but then grows no further.  There is cache activity - it does write and retrieve kernels from the cache after this point.  But the file size / number of cache entries does not grow any further, which makes me think older items are being evicted from the cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for taking so long to respond. I just found this is a bug in libcuda. I will submit a fix shortly.

For now, a workaround is to set `CUDA_CACHE_MAXSIZE` to 2Gb-1 (`2147483647`). Setting it to a value between 2Gb and 4Gb-1 could end up with a really high cache size, and setting it to 4Gb should result in a cache size of 256Mb, which is the default cache size since R334, instead of 32Mb, as said [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-understand-fat-binaries-jit-caching/).

I hope this workaround will help you.